# SQL Server 2008 - Put database user permissions back in after restore without sa privileges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

What would be the best way to allow users to manage their own database restores from backup files? The reason I ask is because I have a user  who is the db_owner for
 a db. He loses access as soon as he restores the database from a backup file from another instance(of course because he does not have access on that instance), and
 then someone with sa permissions has to restore his permissions. Is there anyway he can restore the backups, and then put back the db owner permission on the database that he already had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet at this point is to create a custom stored procedure that does the following style pseudo code:

1. Take the database name, backup file name
2. Check to make sure the person requesting is the owner
3. Restore the database over the original
4. Set the owner back to the original in #2

Build in some logic to check and make sure people aren't trying to abuse it, give bad values, etc. Sign the procedure with a certificate and use a special account just for this purpose to lock down possible intruders/malicious people.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.. I'm new to the signing with certificate thing.. Are you able to point me to a sample for this? .. Also, using this approach, will the users be able to use their regular domain accounts while doing the restore?

Comment: If you create the procedure to use an account that can do the restores (hence the signing) then the regular user doesn't need to have any special rights. That's why I put in that you should check to make sure someone isn't trying to restore over another's database by making sure they are the owner. Erland has a great blog on the signing and counter singing. http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates